# Set fallback page for SPENGO on IBM websphere 6.1 / 8.0

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, spnego

How do I set the fallback page for websphere 6.1 and websphere 8.0?
When I could not load the SPENGO login, I want to have a fallback page to show the simple form login page? Is this possible? Is so, how do I set it up for websphere 6.1 and 8.0?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is done very differently.

In WebSphere Application Server v6.1 SPNEGO is implemented by the TAI (Trust Association Iterceptor). There is no automatic fallback to default login mechanism, however you can do it by yourself. There are two properties - `spnegoNotSupportedPage` and `NTLMTokenReceivedPage` - where you can provide custom pages, which would allow users to access application and bypass SPNEGO challenge e.g. by addinin `&noSPNEGO` to URL.

For more detailed description of these properties look here - [SPNEGO TAI custom properties configuration](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rsec_SPNEGO_tai_attribs.html?cp=SSAW57_6.1.0%2F1-15-4-782&lang=en)

In WebSphere Application Server v7 and later SPNEGO is implemented by the web authenticator. It is not configured via TAI properties, but via `Global Security > SPNEGO web authentication`, there you have option `Allow fall back to application authentication mechanism`, which will kick in if SPNEGO login fails.

In some cases, default fall back may not work and you will need to define similar properties like in v6.1, but this time via SPNEGO web authentication filter.

For more details look here:
[SPNEGO web authentication enablement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/usec_kerb_SPNEGO_config.html?lang=en)
[SPNEGO web authentication filter](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/usec_kerb_SPNEGO_edit.html?lang=en)